# Insert line breaks in long string -- word wrap

Tags: string, r

Here is a function I wrote to break a long string into lines not longer than a given length

```
strBreakInLines <- function(s, breakAt=90, prepend="") {
  words <- unlist(strsplit(s, " "))
  if (length(words)<2) return(s)
  wordLen <- unlist(Map(nchar, words))
  lineLen <- wordLen[1]
  res <- words[1]
  lineBreak <- paste("\n", prepend, sep="")
  for (i in 2:length(words)) {
    lineLen <- lineLen+wordLen[i]
    if (lineLen < breakAt) 
      res <- paste(res, words[i], sep=" ")
    else {
      res <- paste(res, words[i], sep=lineBreak)
      lineLen <- 0
    }
  }
  return(res)
}
```

It works for the problem I had; but I wonder if I can learn something here. Is there a shorter or more efficient solution, especially can I get rid of the for loop?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

How about this:

```
gsub('(.{1,90})(\\s|$)', '\\1\n', s)
```

It will break string "s" into lines with maximum 90 chars (excluding the line break character "\n", but including inter-word spaces), unless there is a word itself exceeding 90 chars, then that word itself will occupy a whole line.

By the way, your function seems broken --- you should replace

```
lineLen <- 0
```

with

```
lineLen <- wordLen[i]
```

Comment: Great Solution! I feel I need to learn about regular expressions, Thanks for pointing out the mistake in my function, too.

Comment: Could you add a note explaining what each part does specifically?

Answer (score 41):

For the sake of completeness, Karsten W.'s comment points at `strwrap`, which is the easiest function to remember:

```
strwrap("Lorem ipsum... you know the routine", width=10)
```

and to match exactly the solution proposed in the question, the string has to be pasted afterwards:

```
paste(strwrap(s,90), collapse="\n")
```

<sub>This post is deliberately made community wiki since the honor of finding the function isn't mine.</sub>

Comment: If you need this as a function, you can also modify `strwrap` in `sapply` for the following User defined formula: 

    `trimmer <- function(x,break_limit){
    sapply(strwrap(x, break_limit, simplify=FALSE), paste, collapse="\n") 
    } `

Answer (score 21):

For further completeness, there's:

- `stringi::stri_wrap`
- `stringr::str_wrap` (which just ultimately calls `stringi::stri_wrap`

The `stringi` version will deal with character sets better (it's built on the ICU library) and it's in C/C++ so it'll ultimately be faster than `base::strwrap`. It's also vectorized over the `str` parameter.

Answer (score 5):

You can look at e.g. the `write.dcf()` FUNCTION in R itself; it also uses a loop so nothing to be ashamed of here.

The first goal is to get it right --- see Chambers (2008).

Comment: Inspecting write.dcf (and then formatDL) brought up the function strwrap which does exactly what my function tries to do.

Comment: Perfect -- I knew there was something but I didn't immediately find it. I needed this once for CRANberries as well...