# Inserting line breaks in long strings

Tags: regex, string, r

I'm writing a function to write automacilly tables in tex format. One problem I'm having is with tables with long strings. To solve this, I created a function that break long strings in more rows. My functions breaks in every space that have at leat `len` characters before (it doesn't break words). I want change this rule to: Break in every space that the next space has at least `len` characters (in other words, I don't want 'substrings' with more than `len` characters, except that cases where a word has more than 10 characters).

```
 quebra <- function(text, len=30) {
  trim <- function(x) gsub('^ *|(?<= ) | *$', '', x, perl=TRUE)
  quebrado <- strsplit(trim(paste(text)),paste0('(?<=.{',len,'}) '), perl=T)
  tam <- max(sapply(quebrado, length))
  out <- sapply(quebrado, function(x, tam) x[1:tam], tam=tam)
  out[is.na(out)] <- ''
  out
 }
```

Example:

`quebra('1234567890 123456789 123456789', 10)` is returning:

```
     [,1]                 
[1,] "1234567890"         
[2,] "123456789 123456789"
```

but I want:

```
     [,1]                 
[1,] "1234567890"         
[2,] "123456789"
[3,] "123456789"
```

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351744/insert-line-breaks-in-long-string-word-wrap) should work, but I could not adapt it to `strsplit()` format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Just use `strwrap`.