# How to split a cell on N number of words?

Tags: r, dplyr, strsplit

I have a data frame with a column that contains long text, and I would like to split it every 30 words, creating the necessary new rows with exactly the same contents in the other columns. The character solution does not work as I need it to work, and that is why I am posting this different question.

```
df1<-data_frame(V1=c(1, 2, 3), V2=c('Red', 'Blue', 'Red'), text=c('Folly words widow one downs few age every seven. If miss part by fact he park just shew. Discovered had get considered projection who favourable. Necessary up knowledge it tolerably. Unwilling departure education is be dashwoods or an. Use off agreeable law unwilling sir deficient curiosity instantly. Easy mind life fact with see has bore ten. Parish any chatty can elinor direct for former. Up as meant widow equal an share least', 'Bringing unlocked me an striking ye perceive. Mr by wound hours oh happy. Me in resolution pianoforte continuing we. Most my no spot felt by no. He he in forfeited furniture sweetness he arranging. Me tedious so to behaved written account ferrars moments. Too objection for elsewhere her preferred allowance her. Marianne shutters mr steepest to me. Up mr ignorant produced distance although is sociable blessing. Ham whom call all lain like.', 'Did shy say mention enabled through elderly improve. As at so believe account evening behaved hearted is. House is tiled we aware. It ye greatest removing concerns an overcame appetite. Manner result square father boy behind its his. Their above spoke match ye mr right oh as first. Be my depending to believing perfectly concealed household. Point could to built no hours smile sense.Breakfast agreeable incommode departure it an. By ignorant at on wondered relation. Enough at tastes really so cousin am of. Extensive therefore supported by extremity of contented. Is pursuit compact demesne invited elderly be. View him she roof tell her case has sigh. Moreover is possible he admitted sociable concerns. By in cold no less been sent hard hill.' ))
```

I have tried the following:

```
df <- df1%>%
      mutate(text = strsplit(as.character(text), "\\W+{30}")) %>%
      unnest(text)
```

But it just doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert line breaks in long string -- word wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351744/insert-line-breaks-in-long-string-word-wrap)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, this asks for number of words, not number of characters

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option with `separate_rows` and then `paste` it together

```
df1 %>%
   separate_rows(text) %>%
   group_by(V1) %>%
   group_by(V2, grp = ((row_number()-1) %/%30) + 1, add = TRUE) %>% 
   summarise(text = paste(text, collapse= ' ')) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-grp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me.

```
str_match_all(text, "(?:\\w+\\W*){30}")
```