# How to get x axis text to have a vertical orientation (NOT rotated with angle=90/270)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want my X axis text to look like:

**J

a

n**

not be rotated with the letters turned.

I want to keep it as a date axis. I know I could make it discrete with values of `"J\na\na\n"` for instance. Perhaps I can map a vector of values like that over the axis.text.x values? It seems like there should be an easier way though.

Below will demonstrate the issue. I've rotated it 90 degrees but as shown above this is not what I want.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)

y<- c(52014,51598,61920,58135,71242,76254,63882,64768,53526,55290,45490,35602)
months<-seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"),as.Date("2018-12-01"),"month")
dat<-as.tibble(cbind(y,months)) %>% 
  mutate(month=as.Date(months,origin="1970-01-01"))

ggplot(dat) +
  geom_line(aes(x=month,y=y)) +
  scale_x_date(breaks=date_breaks("month"),labels=date_format("%b")) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90))
```

Comment: Several suggestions here: [Insert line breaks in long string — word wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351744/insert-line-breaks-in-long-string-word-wrap)

Comment: I will try, but I was not assuming that I could use string functions on a date type column. the "Jan" "Feb" etc. come from using `scale_x_date(breaks="month")`.

Comment: Perhaps use the `labels` argument? Also, it's much easier to help if you provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Tried the `gsub` function method, got an error that appeared to be due to the column type. Added an example to my original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example data :

```
date <- seq(from = as.Date("2000-01-01"), to = as.Date("2000-12-01"), by = "month")
df <- data.frame(Month = date, Value = rnorm(12))
```

First, produce a custom set of dates you want. Here I use `strsplit()` and `lapply` to achieve your request.(`month.name` and `month.abb` are native character vectors in R )

```
mon.split <- strsplit(month.name, "")
mon <- unlist(lapply(mon.split, paste0, "\n", collapse = ""))
mon
 [1] "J\na\nn\nu\na\nr\ny\n"       "F\ne\nb\nr\nu\na\nr\ny\n"   
 [3] "M\na\nr\nc\nh\n"             "A\np\nr\ni\nl\n"            
 [5] "M\na\ny\n"                   "J\nu\nn\ne\n"               
 [7] "J\nu\nl\ny\n"                "A\nu\ng\nu\ns\nt\n"         
 [9] "S\ne\np\nt\ne\nm\nb\ne\nr\n" "O\nc\nt\no\nb\ne\nr\n"      
[11] "N\no\nv\ne\nm\nb\ne\nr\n"    "D\ne\nc\ne\nm\nb\ne\nr\n"
```

I supposed your date variable is 'Date' class so I use `scale_x_date`. If it's numeric or character, use `scale_x_continuous` and `scale_x_discrete`.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Month, y = Value)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(breaks = date, labels = mon)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is what I assumed was possible. I didn't know about `month.name` (is that some kind of constant built in to R?). I will use `month.abb` which I discovered also exists.

Comment: Glad to help you. `month.name` and `month.abb` are native character vectors in R.

Comment: In case anyone else reads this, `breaks=date_breaks("month")` did not work. I had to switch it to `breaks=MY.DATE`.