# How to fit a text tooltip in the screen (ggplotly R)

Tags: r, r-plotly

When generating a plotly geom_point() plot with a tooltip that contains a long description, the package's standard is to show the text in a single line. The issue with that is that it does not fit in the screen. How is it possible to break the line, in a way that it can be read?

```
 library(tidyverse)
 library(plotly)


bd <- data.frame(Freq = c(1, 2, 3),
                     Criticality = c("A", "B", "C"),
                     Status = c("alpha", "beta", "alpha"),
                     Plant = c(1, 2, 1),
                     Description = c("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                                      "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy",
                                      "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"))

    g <- bd %>% 
       ggplot(aes(x = Freq, y = Criticality)) +
      geom_point(aes(shape = Status, col = Plant, text = Description)) +
      geom_jitter(aes(shape = Status, col = Plant, text = Description)) +
      guides(size = FALSE)

    ggplotly(g, tooltip = c("Description"))
```

Currently, I get the following error message but it does not generate any problem.

```
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: text
```

Comment: the warning seems related to 'text=Description' in aes() in your geom_point and geom_jitter (try removing it); in regards to long description for a tooltip, take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55643887/format-tooltip-in-plotly-for-long-text-labels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the strings have no spaces, I would use the method suggested by Ben. If there are spaces, you can use `str_wrap()`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

bd <-
  tibble(
    Freq = c(1, 2, 3),
    Criticality = c("A", "B", "C"),
    Status = c("alpha", "beta", "alpha"),
    Plant = c(1, 2, 1),
    Description = paste(sentences[1:3], collapse = " "),
    tooltip = str_wrap(Description, 30)
  )

g <- bd %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Freq, y = Criticality)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = Status, col = Plant, label = tooltip)) +
  geom_jitter(aes(shape = Status, col = Plant, label = tooltip)) +
  guides(size = FALSE)

ggplotly(g, tooltip = c("tooltip"))
```

[image]

Comment: That's great to hear. Please go ahead and mark the answer as solved.